# JQuery element custom knockout customBinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, coffeescript, custom-binding

I'm trying to make a knockout binding to a jQuery object that is capable of knowing about any changes to the dom (attributes, text, html, appending, deleting. etc).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.jqHtml =
  init: (element, valueAccessor) ->
    $(element).preMutate (options, el) ->
      if ko.isObservable valueAccessor()
        valueAccessor().valueWillMutate()
    $(element).onMutate _.debounce (argsCollection) =>
      @argsCollection = argsCollection
      if ko.isObservable valueAccessor()
        valueAccessor().valueHasMutated()
    , 100

  update: (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) ->
    content = valueAccessor()
    $(element).children().each( (i,el) -> ko.cleanNode(el) )
    if _.difference($(element).children().get(), content.get()).length > 0 || _.difference(content.get(),$(element).children().get()).length > 0
      $(element).children().peek().detach().unpeek()
      $(element).peek().append(content).unpeek()
    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(viewModel, element)
```

I have an in progress [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92xsX/117/)

The problem as made clear by the jsfiddle, that jquery won't keep track of duplicates in the dom, and instead moves elements around. So if I have multiple bindings to the same jq element, jQuery will only be able to place it in one data-binding. I'm thinking there might be a way to create a jqObservable, which holds in it the original jquery element, and then distributes out copies of that element. And whenever onMutate notified, then it will update each of those copies. Of course I'll need an inception blocker (data-binding to the same element underneath an already bound element). One issue I can think og is knowing which subsciption is calling the observable to know which copy of the jquery element to return so it doesn't return the wrong copy, and knowing to destroy elements which have been unbound/unsubscribed from. Also I'd need to update the rest of the jquery copies when one of them is modified. By the way, I don't care if it's modified outside of jQuery functions, only jQuery functions should be called on the elements in this plugin.

Any Suggestions would be much obliged.

P.S.

OnMutate is my own custom jQuery plugin

I was originally trying to subscribe to change events, but that wasn't going to work for anything other than inputs. There was no top level subscribe for subtree modifications, and the closest thing was refreshing every second to check for differences in the html. Another option was another plugin I saw on stack overflow, [jollytoad's mutation events](https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events)

It only worked for a few functions though, but it gave me the idea of creating callbacks for all elements I need them on and nothing more, so i created this function to automate creating callbacks for as many jQuery functions as I wanted, and any other plugins. Which I created below.

```
(($, window) ->
  hasArgs = () -> arguments.length > 0
  noArgs = () -> arguments.length == 0
  class DomCallbacks
    ###*
     * Defines the jQuery functions to create callbacks for, and which type of callback they contain
     * @type {defaults}
     *   @properties {array of jQuery function names, and test to determine if the callback 
     *   should be run based on input to the jQuery function, passed the same arguments that the jQuery
     *   function is}
    ###
    defaults:
      Mutate: 
        jqfuncs: ["addClass","append","appendTo","attr","clone","css","detach","empty","hasClass","height","html","innerHeight","innerWidth","insertAfter","insertBefore","offset","outerHeight","outerWidth","position","prepend","prependTo","prop","remove","removeAttr","removeClass","removeProp","replaceAll","replaceWith","scrollLeft","scrollTop","text","toggleClass","unwrap","val","width","wrap","wrapAll","wrapInner"]
        defaultCheck: hasArgs
      Look: 
        jqfuncs:["addClass","after",'append',"appendTo","attr","before","clone","css","detach","empty","hasClass","height","html","innerHeight","innerWidth","insertAfter","insertBefore","offset","outerHeight","outerWidth","position","prepend","prependTo","prop","remove","removeAttr","removeClass","removeProp","replaceAll","replaceWith","scrollLeft","scrollTop","text","toggleClass","unwrap","val","width","wrap","wrapAll","wrapInner"]
        defaultCheck: noArgs

    constructor: (options) ->
      @categories = $.extend({}, @defaults, options)

    originals: {} 

    ###*
     * Creates a function in jQuery's function object by replacing the name with a wrapper function
     * and then calling the original function, and has the new function call each category of callback
     * for the starting element and it's parents
     * @param {string} name       the name/key of the function being replaced
     * @param {string} categories the type of callback that the function should notify
    ###
    addCallback: (name, categories) ->
      pairs = (obj) ->
        pairs = []
        for key of obj 
          if (hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key))
            pairs.push([key, obj[key]])
        pairs

      if !@originals[name]?
        @originals[name] = $.fn[name]
      _this = @

      categories = $.grep pairs(categories), (pair) ->
        $.grep(pair[1].jqfuncs, (val) -> val.name == name || val == name).length > 0
      ###*
       * The actual wrapper function being created
       * @return {object} returns the original functions return
      ###
      $.fn[name] =  () ->
        options = {args: arguments}
        ittr = []
        if !$.fn[name].peek          
          ittrArray = for category in categories
            key = category[0]
            val = category[1]
            funcs = ($.grep(val.jqfuncs, (checking) -> checking.name == name || checking == name)).slice(0,1)[0].check
            {key:key, val: val ,funcs:funcs}

          for ittr in ittrArray
            if !ittr.funcs?
              ittr.funcs = ittr.val.defaultCheck
            if !ittr.funcs? or ittr.funcs.apply(@,arguments)
              @["pre"+ittr.key](null, options)
              @parents()["pre"+ittr.key](null, options)

        funcRet = _this.originals[name].apply(@, arguments)
        options.funcRet = funcRet

        if !$.fn[name].peek
          for ittr in ittrArray
            if !ittr.funcs?
              ittr.funcs = ittr.val.defaultCheck
            if !ittr.funcs? or ittr.funcs.apply(@,arguments)
              @["on"+ittr.key](null, options)
              @parents()["on"+ittr.key](null, options)

        funcRet

      $.fn[name].peek = false

    ###*
     * restores the original function to it's property in the jQuery function object
     * @param  {string} name key used to find function to restore
     * @return {[type]}      [description]
    ###
    removeCallback: (name) ->
      if @originals[name]?
        $.fn[name] = @originals[name]
        delete @originals[name]  

  ###*
   * Creates a jQuery plugin capable of subscribing to and calling callbacks
   * for each node
   * @param  {string} precedence names the function to run before or after the subscripton function
   * @param  {string} category   the name of the type of
   * @return {function}          returns the function capable of setting and running callbacks for individual elements
  ###
  createCallbackPlugin = (precedence, category) ->
    ###*
     * A jQuery plugin which creates a sets callbacks for elements and calls them if none are passed in
     * @param  {function} callback the callback to be set (optional)
     * @param  {object}   options  options to be sent to the callback, set by the trigger function
     * @return {jQuery}            returns jQuery object for chaining
    ###
    return (callback, options) ->
      @each (i, el)  ->
        if callback?
          if !el['domCallbacks']?
            el['domCallbacks'] = {}
          if !el['domCallbacks']['_'+precedence+category]?
            el['domCallbacks']['_'+precedence+category] = []
          el['domCallbacks']['_'+precedence+category].push callback
        else
          if el['domCallbacks']? && el['domCallbacks']['_'+precedence+category]?
            for cb in el['domCallbacks']['_'+precedence+category]
              cb(options, el)
        @
      @

  domCallbacks = new DomCallbacks()

  ###*
   * This creates each function inside of jQuery capable of setting and running callbacks on
   * individual elements.
   * @param  {[type]} options [description]
   * @return {[type]}         [description]
  ###
  $.extend createDomCallbacks: (options) ->
    $.extend({}, domCallbacks.categories, options)
    categoryFunctions = {}
    for key, category of domCallbacks.categories
      categoryFunctions['pre'+key] = createCallbackPlugin('pre',key)
      categoryFunctions['on'+key] = createCallbackPlugin('on',key)
      $.extend $.fn, categoryFunctions
    for key, category of domCallbacks.categories
      for val in category.jqfuncs
        domCallbacks.addCallback( (if val.name then val.name else val) , domCallbacks.categories)

    ###*
     * removes any callbacks each element in the jquery object
     * @param  {object} options an object conatining keys for the type of callback to be removed (e.g. options = {Mutate: {}})
     * @return {[type]}         returns jquery object for chaining
    ###
    $.extend $.fn, removeDomCallbacks: (options) ->
      @each (i, el) ->
        if el['domCallbacks']?
          if !options?
            delete el['domCallbacks']
          for category of options
            delete el['domCallbacks']["_pre"+category]
            delete el['domCallbacks']["_on"+category]

        @
      @
    ###*
     * turns off all callbacks for performing actions without notifying up the dom
     * @return {jQuery} for chaining
    ###
    $.extend $.fn, peek: () ->
      for key,val of domCallbacks.originals
        $.fn[key].peek = true
      @each (i, el) ->
        @
      @

    ###*
     * turns off all callbacks for performing actions without notifying up the dom
     * @return {jQuery} for chaining
    ###
    $.extend $.fn, unpeek: () ->
      for key,val of domCallbacks.originals
        $.fn[key].peek = false
      @each (i, el) ->
        @
      @

) @jQuery, @
```

Comment: Well there is this from a while ago: [I Want a DAMNodeInserted Event!](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2012/04/25/i-want-a-damnodeinserted/). What are your intentions? It would help to explain as you might get more feedback on ways to do what you want more efficiently if people understand what your are trying to accomplish (how you are trying to use what you've written).

Comment: @Cymen Just wanted to let you know I updated my answer